# Avoiding a potential deadlock / memory leak in a multithreaded application

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, pthreads, deadlock

**Short version**:

How to deal with the non-atomicity of spawning a group of threads, running some custom (unspecified at the time of implementation) callback? Several possible solutions are described below, it seems like using a thread pool is the only good solution. Is there a standard way to deal with it? No need to post complete C++ solutions, pseudocode or a brief description will suffice. Performance is an important aspect here.

Although it may seem trivial, I believe the below fragment of code occurs in many of the existing applications, many (beginning, probably also some of the advanced) programmers may write similar constructs without even realizing the dangers. And the problems are the same for pthread / C++11 `std::thread` / WinAPI and probably many other low-level multithreading libraries. Therefore it is an important question.

**Long version**:

I'm designing some multithreaded application and I decided to make an utility function, where several threads are spawned. This is perhaps a quite common code, it comes up in many of my applications (unless they are using OpenMP):

```
void ParallelCall(void (*function)(int, int), int numThreads)
{
    Thread *threads = new Thread[numThreads - 1];
    for(int i = 1; i < numThreads; ++ i) {
        if(threads[i - 1].start(&function, i, numThreads)) // this might fail
            abort(); // what now?
    }

    (*function)(0, numThreads);
    // use the calling thread as thread 0

    for(int i = 1; i < numThreads; ++ i)
        threads[i - 1].join();
    delete[] threads;
}
```

This is more of a pseudo code for illustration of the problem. A bunch of threads are being created and spawned (the `Thread` object wraps a pthread thread). Then they do something and finally they are joined.

Now the problem: what if, for whatever reason, some of the threads fail to start (may be resource exhaustion or a per-user limit)? I know how to detect that it happened, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

I guess I should wait for the successfully started threads to finish and then throw an exception. However, if the code in `function` contains some synchronization (such as a barrier), this can easily result in a deadlock because the rest of the expected threads will never spawn.

Alternately, I could just throw an exception right away, ignoring the running threads, but then I leave the wrapper objects allocated, causing a memory leak (and also never joining the spawned threads).

Doing stuff like killing the running threads doesn't seem to be a good idea (I'm frankly not quite sure what is the result of forcibly killing a thread of a multithreaded application - seems like the memory will be left in undefined state, which is mostly kind of hard to handle - and could on itself lead to more memory leaks if the callback `function` allocates memory).

Inserting a wait for all the threads to start before letting them enter the callback `function` seems unbearable performance-wise (although it would solve the issue easily). Another option would be to have a pool of spawned threads with associated FIFOs, waiting for tasks, but there is a problem with the number of threads (I would spawn as many threads as there are logical CPUs, but then what if `numThreads` is larger? I would be essentially reimplementing OS' scheduler in my code).

How is this commonly solved? Is there a better way? If not, is a potential (depending on what's in the callback `function`) deadlock better than a memory leak?

Comment: Hilarious... Why on earth are you adding another threading library to the world, with faults designed in?

Comment: make the threads report they're alive... and only wait for the alive ones.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Sure. The real question is how this should be solved? Also these things happen rarely in practice, a perfectly valid solution could also be to terminate the application. But then, from user's perspective, it is better to leave a memory leak, instruct the application to quit (e.g. via exception) and let it save it's state so that it can be recovered by the user after restarting.

Comment: @jsantander As mentioned in the question - I know perfectly well which threads are alive. The real question is what to do with them?

Comment: The other two comments may be right ... but what _could_ you do if you implemented yourself? I guess it would be nice if the threads could be stopped without being killed; the exception could carry references to the thread array and the index of the last valid thread with it and the catcher could deal with them.

Comment: @RichardHodges Because there are not enough of them, of course. And I do believe that many programmers will routinely write a similar code without even thinking about it, hence I believe this is a valid question.

Comment: @PeterSchneider that seems like an interesting solution. I haven't seen that implemented anywhere, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand the problem. Do you mean what to do if your threads fail to start? Change "fail to start" with "memory fails to allocate" and ask the question again. Can your application work correctly without those threads? If the application is been shut down, and unless you are in some embedded system, the OS will clean up after you, either memory-wise or thread-wise. If you're afraid of waiting for non-started threads, and you know which ones are alive, then only wait for those...

Comment: @jsantander This is not the same problem though. If the first thread fails to start, it is all good and the function simply fails (e.g. via exception or an error code). Then it is up to the caller to decide whether the application can continue or not. But if some threads are already running and a thread fails to start, it becomes a different problem entirely, as someone needs to deal with the threads already started.

Comment: @theswine You may consider a static mutexed lock before calling `new()`! Badlyy asked question though :-( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure how would that even help? The error will not happen inside `new`, it will happen in `Thread::start()`. Perhaps I should highlight that in the code listing above.

Comment: If you're dying, the OS will take care of you and your resources (at least desktop/server OS will). If you really want to orderly die, your (alive) threads might be running on a `while(iAmToStop()) {...}` that you switch off for them to head to dying. What can you do with a thread really will depend a lot in your threading library and OS, whether you can stop them, signal them or kill them.

Comment: @jsantander I don't want to always die. This is up to the caller to decide. Also the living threads are likely to calculate something math heavy and it is not possible to insert explicit checking whether to stop (the loop might be contained in a math library where the caller don't have access to the source code).

Comment: ok... then, my recommendation is to avoid the problem by not starting/stopping threads during runtime or to solve a particular request. As you indicated in the question: start a set of threads during initialization (in similar number to the OS processors) and send jobs to them for execution.

Comment: @jsantander Yes, that was one of the solutions I considered before asking the question.

Comment: [SEDA: An Architecture for Scalable, Well-Conditioned Internet Services](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/talks/seda-sosp01-talk.pdf)

Comment: @jsantander Yes, I know how these things work and also know why the fork/join model is bad. In my context, MAGMA would be more relevant. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Updated my answer to iunclude complete source code. This is 100% safe unless one of the parallel tasklets throws an exception. You can even catch that with a little more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you solve this problem:

Create each thread in such a way that it waits on a sentinel before it's allowed to begin the user's work function (you'll need a lambda that calls it)
If any of the threads fail to start, set a flag to indicate that existing threads should all finish immediately rather than perform the user's function.
In the error case, join the threads that did start. Then exit with an error code or exception as you wish (exception is better).

Now your function is thread safe and will not leak memory.

EDIT: here's some code that does what you want, including a test.
If you want to force a simulation of a thread failing, recompile with `INTRODUCE_FAILURE` defined to `1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <system_error>
#include <condition_variable>

#define INTRODUCE_FAILURE 0
// implementation

void ParallelCall(void (*function)(int, int), int numThreads)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(numThreads-1);

    std::atomic<bool> mustAbort ( false );
    std::atomic<bool> mayRun ( false );
    std::mutex conditionMutex;
    std::condition_variable runCondition;

    for(int i = 1; i < numThreads; ++ i) {
        try {
            #if INTRODUCE_FAILURE == 1
            if (i == 3) {
                throw std::system_error(99, std::generic_category(),  "the test deliberately failed a thread");
            }
            #endif
            threads.emplace_back( std::thread{ [i, numThreads, function
                                , &mustAbort
                                , &conditionMutex
                                , &runCondition
                                , &mayRun]()->int {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock(conditionMutex);
                runCondition.wait(myLock, [&mayRun]()->bool { 
                    return mayRun;
                });
                myLock.unlock();
                // wait for permission
                if (!mustAbort) {
                    function(i, numThreads);
                }
                return 0;
            }} );
        }
        catch(std::exception& e) { // will be a std::system_error
            mustAbort = true;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock(conditionMutex);
            mayRun = true;
            conditionMutex.unlock();
            runCondition.notify_all();
            for(auto& t : threads) {
                t.join();
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> myLock(conditionMutex);
    mayRun = true;
    conditionMutex.unlock();
    runCondition.notify_all();

    function(0, numThreads);
    // use the calling thread as thread 0

    for(auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}

// test

using namespace std;

void testFunc(int index, int extent) {
    static std::mutex outputMutex;

    unique_lock<mutex> myLock(outputMutex);
    cout << "Executing " << index << " of " << extent << endl;
    myLock.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds(2000) );

    myLock.lock();
    cout << "Finishing " << index << " of " << extent << endl;
    myLock.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    try {
        cout << "initiating parallel call" << endl;
        ParallelCall(testFunc, 10);
        cout << "parallel call complete" << endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
        cout << "Parallel call failed because: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Example output on success:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
initiating parallel call
Executing 0 of 10
Executing 1 of 10
Executing 4 of 10
Executing 5 of 10
Executing 8 of 10
Executing 2 of 10
Executing 7 of 10
Executing 6 of 10
Executing 9 of 10
Executing 3 of 10
Finishing 1 of 10
Finishing 5 of 10
Finishing 2 of 10
Finishing 9 of 10
Finishing 8 of 10
Finishing 4 of 10
Finishing 3 of 10
Finishing 0 of 10
Finishing 6 of 10
Finishing 7 of 10
parallel call complete
```

Example output on failure:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
initiating parallel call
Parallel call failed because: the test deliberately failed a thread: Cannot assign requested address
```

Finally a plea - do not unleash your library on the world. The std::thread library is very comprehensive, and if that isn't enough we have OpenMP, TBB, etc. etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's a ... lot of code. I really appreciate it, although I also mentioned this possibility in the original question but deemed it too expensive performance-wise. As for the final request, I can't promise anything, I am a computer scientist and I kind of get paid to develop new and outrageous stuff. But I get your point and would otherwise 100% agree.

Comment: :-) mutithreading is really hard to make safe. The amount of code it takes often surprises people. The problem is the myriad of crossing cases that grow exponentially with each additional thread.

Comment: I know that it is hard, I was just surprised that you wrote so much code without actually introducing anything new. I really appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: Um... what was introduced was preventing both deadlocks and memory leaks - i.e. making the function robust. It takes a lot of code because it's not trivial. I was hoping you'd gain some insight from it. Have you taken a close look at the code and compiled and run it on your own machine?

Comment: No, I have not run it but I did have read it. I unfortunately forgot to mention that C++11 is out of the question. You introduced an implementation of what I proposed in the original question ("Inserting a wait for all the threads to start before letting them enter the callback" - which is what you did, please correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not a beginning programmer, and I was capable of writing that myself. Make no mistake, this is not a simple question, despite it does seem trivial, and most of the other readers dismiss it rather quickly. I really appreciate your effort (+1).

Comment: fair enough, I guess you can replace std:: with boost:: (or roll your own) and use functors in place of lambdas. Anyway, it was a fun exercise to write it.
Btw, best thing you can do for your firm is to get them to upgrade to c++11. You will reduce development times because you'll have fewer bugs.

Answer (score 1):

How about letting the threads that did get created help out by doing the lost work before they exit their threadproc?

```
List _StillBornWork;

void ParallelCall(void (*function)(int, int), int numThreads)
{
    Thread *threads = new Thread[numThreads - 1];
    for(int i = 1; i < numThreads; ++ i) {
        if(threads[i - 1].start(&function, i, numThreads)) {
            _StillBornWork.Push(i);
        }
    }

    (*function)(0, numThreads);
    // use the calling thread as thread 0

    for(int i = 1; i < numThreads; ++ i)
        threads[i - 1].join();
    delete[] threads;
}

ThreadProc(int i) {

  while(1) {
    do work

    // Here we see if there was any work that didn't get done because its thread
    // was stilborn.  In your case, the work is indicated by the integer i.
    // If we get work, loop again, else break.
    if (!_StillBornWork.Pop(&i))
      break;  // no more work that wasn't done.
  }

}
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution, but still will work only in simple cases such as processing an array. For some algorithms (e.g. parallel FFT) it could be hard to accept that if asked to run 8 concurrent threads, only 3 are running, as the threads would be waiting for themselves at the end of each stage in order to be able to start the next one - but if there are only three, the stage never gets finished. Still, an interesting workarround.

Comment: @Swine. Not sure what you mean about waiting.  Can you explain that a little more?

Comment: well, in the user code (inside `function`), there will often be some synchronization. If the computation is staged (such as FFT, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram), the threads will contain synchronization points (e.g. barriers) that prevent the faster threads progressing to the next stage before the rest of the threads finished processing the current stage. This synchronization (this wait) will keep the threads waiting forever (deadlock), if not all of the expected threads are launched and running.

Comment: You could add the call to check for missing work prior to the barrier.  However, what you are essentially doing here is modeling a producer consumer work queue.  You have 2 types of work.  One type is the FFT.  The second type is an FFT stage. You add the work to do the FFT to the queue.  It spawns work to do the first stage and then waits for all that work to complete.  When all the stages finish, the FFT thread spawns work to do the next stage, etc.

Comment: Well, sure, you could have a single stage as one parallel call and the next state as another parallel call, the join in between taking care of the synchronization. However, spawning threads costs significantly more time than just synchronizing them. Also, not every algorithm is as simple as FFT (most of them are not), and the fork/join model is less and less used nowadays. The goal here was to provide an inherently safe parallel call, without the need of the user function checking for anything it wouldn't usually check for.

Comment: First, I would avoid creating threads since as they cost so much to create.  You definitely want some sort of pool.  Second, your problem is just a variation of the work queue pattern.  it is why complex parallel programs use work queues instead of trying to do what you are doing.

Comment: Another solution would be to create your worker threads once at startup.  Instead of calling the OS to create threads when you wanted to do your ParallelCall, you simply grabbed the threads you already had, which obviously wont fail to create.

Comment: I have an edit for my comment above...  It wont take my edit.  I said spawn WORK not a THREAD.  :)  That should be the cost of atomically sticking a work item on a linked list.  Second, your problem is just a variation of the work queue pattern.  The issue you are presenting is just one of many issues that drive complex parallel programs to use work queues and pools of worker threads.